# Is it possible to do an advanced compare of two apps based on instalation history?

Tags: applications

Is there any tool which classifies apps by their features. Something like Pandora (music genome) for apps (apps genome).

For example I installed 'Chess Free' and after 3 months I installed 'Free Chess' (app2). Can I somehow see a matrix which would say: app2 can save games (unlike app1), app1 I can customize figure icons. (to better see the king vs. queen). App 2 has ads on top (app1 does not).
Perhaps this is asking too much. and Google may not like it so it would have to bee from external start-up.

Or alternatively (no matrix) - can I only read reviews of users who (1) wrote a review for app2 and (2) also have installed app1 and (3) mention app1 name in their review. (i.e., "app2 in comparison to app1 review").

Or any server which comes close to this vision?

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly what you asked, but [Mapsaurus Beta](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mapsaurus.apps) comes close to it. You can also use the corresponding website: [Mapsaurus](http://mapsaurus.com/): Just enter the app you look for "alikes", and it shows you related apps:

[image: Mapsaurus]

Click on one of them, and the tree continues. A separate frame (not shown in my picture) gives you the Playstore link to the centered app. The screenshot was made from the website.